# event to identify Call Answering In Android

Tags: android

Hi i am developing call recording application. I want to know call answering event. For example if the user lift the call then i have to start recording. How to know whether he answered a call or not

Answer (score 0):

http://peacemoon.wordpress.com/2009/08/06/android-listening-to-incomingoutgoing-phone-calls/

```
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
    //CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
// do ur work here(after receiving call)
    break;
```

Comment: Hi Dabhi i did that already. The problem is with listeners. Listeners are calling lot of times. I print log in ringing, offhook and idle. They are calling lot of time in a call.

Comment: offhook event execute when u receiving call otherwise not, so ur start recording in this event.i do the same thing in my application. ii had started my application's activity on incoming call if it is exist in my application's database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `BroadcastReceiver` and listen for the [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED) events. `ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` is the one you should listen.